# Moving an slice item from one position to another in go

Tags: go

I' trying to move an item from one position to another inside a slice. [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JsYZ6TgKWQ)

```
indexToRemove := 1
indexWhereToInsert := 4

slice := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}    

slice = append(slice[:indexToRemove], slice[indexToRemove+1:]...)
fmt.Println("slice:", slice)    

newSlice := append(slice[:indexWhereToInsert], 1)
fmt.Println("newSlice:", newSlice)

slice = append(newSlice, slice[indexWhereToInsert:]...)
fmt.Println("slice:", slice)
```

This produces to following output:

```
slice: [0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
newSlice: [0 2 3 4 1]
slice: [0 2 3 4 1 1 6 7 8 9]
```

But I would expect the output be like this:

```
slice: [0 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
newSlice: [0 2 3 4 1]
slice: [0 2 3 4 1 **5** 6 7 8 9]
```

Where is my fault?

Comment: A slice is an object that references an array (Flimzy's answer). Also keep in mind that you can actually use bare arrays in go, but they are quite unwieldy compared to slices. They can be useful in certain circumstances though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `newSlice` is not a distinct copy of `slice`--they reference the same underlying array.

So when you assign to `newSlice`, you're modifying the underlying array, and thus `slice`, too.

To remedy this, you need to make an explicit copy:

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/P74nOrHN3j)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    indexToRemove := 1
    indexWhereToInsert := 4

    slice := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

    val := slice[indexToRemove]

    slice = append(slice[:indexToRemove], slice[indexToRemove+1:]...)
    fmt.Println("slice:", slice)    

    newSlice := make([]int, indexWhereToInsert+1)
    copy(newSlice,slice[:indexWhereToInsert])
    newSlice[indexWhereToInsert]=val
    fmt.Println("newSlice:", newSlice)
    fmt.Println("slice:", slice)

    slice = append(newSlice, slice[indexWhereToInsert:]...)
    fmt.Println("slice:", slice)    
}
```

(Note that I've also added the `val` variable, rather than hardcoding `1` as the value to be inserted.)

Comment: This explains a lot! I thought that append return a new slice. Tanks!

Comment: @David: [Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) would be some good reading for you.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue before and I solved as:

```
func insertInt(array []int, value int, index int) []int {
    return append(array[:index], append([]int{value}, array[index:]...)...)
}

func removeInt(array []int, index int) []int {
    return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}

func moveInt(array []int, srcIndex int, dstIndex int) []int {
    value := array[srcIndex]
    return insertInt(removeInt(array, srcIndex), value, dstIndex)
}


func main() {
    slice := []int{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

    fmt.Println("slice: ", slice)

    slice = insertInt(slice, 2, 5)  
    fmt.Println("slice: ", slice)

    slice = removeInt(slice, 5) 
    fmt.Println("slice: ", slice)

    slice = moveInt(slice, 1, 4) 
    fmt.Println("slice: ", slice)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Sfu1VsySieS

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple shift right example without copy but also includes a loop showing how it's all really pointers.

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LCzr-Wr4ZxL)

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    for _, e := range s {
        // Will always shift 2 as it's been shifted each time
        fmt.Println(e, shiftRight(s, e))
    }
}

func shiftRight(s []int, e int) []int {
    if len(s) > 1 { // No where to shift to if 1 item
        // Go through the slice finding the item to shift
        for i, item := range s {
            if item == e {
                if i == len(s)-1 {
                    break // already at the end, can't shift any further
                }
                s[i] = s[i+1]
                s[i+1] = item
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the omotto's version with generics:

```
func insertInt[T any](array []T, value T, index int) []T {
    return append(array[:index], append([]T{value}, array[index:]...)...)
}

func removeInt[T any](array []T, index int) []T {
    return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}

func moveElement[T any](array []T, srcIndex int, dstIndex int) []T {
    value := array[srcIndex]
    return insertInt(removeInt(array, srcIndex), value, dstIndex)
}
```